# Передать текст ссылки в input по классу

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="Открывает модальное окно Bootstrap" class="link">Текст ссылки</a>
<div class="Модальное окно Bootstrap">
<input type="text" class="get_text">
</div>
```

Как передать текст ссылки `.link` в value инпута `.get_text`, не пользуясь ID, а только классами?

Пробовал так:

```
 onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('get_text').value='Текст ссылки'"
```

Не работает так.

UPD Решение нащёл на jQuery

```
 onclick="jQuery('.item_name').val('Текст ссылки');"
```

Comment: Название метода `getElementsByClassName()`, говорит как бы о том, что Вы получаете не один элемент, а `array-like object`.

Comment: А почему такой изврат? Почему не `querySelector`, если id не устраивает?

Comment: А в целом, конечно, навык чтения - очень важен. И надо бы читать правильно, что возвращает метод `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

Как в целом, уже написали в комментариях, getElementsByClassName - возвращает что-то вроде массива, и вы пытаетесь установить value для массива, а не для инпута.
Самым легким решением будет написать querySelector(".get_text") этот метод может обращаться к любому селектору (мной указана точка, так как мы обращаемся к классу, если бы был нужен id, нужно было бы поставить #)
Подключать jquery уже преступление я считаю
А вообще, учите основы перед тем как что-то делать, и читайте описания методов, которые используете, getElementsByClassName - там даже в названии elementS - то есть несколько